# MVC4 DropDownList error new { @onchange = "this.form.submit();" })

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I've started a MVC4 application in VS2012 and need a submit on change of selection in a dropdown list, doing this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("FindProject", "All", new{onchange = "document.getElementById('TheForm').submit();"})
```

but the browser reports:
**Compiler Error Message: CS1928: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper>' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownList' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownList(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, object)' has some invalid arguments**

Leaving out the: `new{onchange = "document.getElementById('TheForm').submit();"}`

removes the error but also leaves out any possibility to make a submit on change...

Whats wrong, there are nummerous examples on the net showing this Works ?

What can I do/change ?

Comment: The second parameters is expected to be `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and not (the string) `"All"`.

Comment: Why does it Work without - do you know of a quick default alternative ?

Comment: What `<option>` tags do you need to have in that drop-down element?

Comment: Are the form elements wrapped within a form ? If yes, check this [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/working-with-dropdownlist-in-mvc-5/)

Comment: Thanks for hint about the "All" - this was copied from the net and has been replaced by: (SelectList)ViewData["FindProject"]
and the desired on change is now: new{onchange = "submit();"}